# Big django queryset in Python's if conditional expression

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have a queryset that was used in below code.

```
result = 1 if queryset else 0
```

In case of small queryset it's okay but when queryset gets bigger (more than 500 000 results) program freezes, it takes some time to stop it.

What is happening behind the scenes when Django's queryset is tested in the code above?
Is some extra work performed during that check?

Even though the queryset is big, there is no problem with calling `count()` or `iterator()` or any other methods, it is that conditional expression where the problem appears.

Edit:
Queryset is too big. It populates Queryset's `self._result_cache`. Same thing happens for `len()` and iterating over queryset in a for loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python will either use the `__bool__` or `__len__` methods to [test the truth value](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) of an object, and it looks like the implementation for the `Queryset` class fetches all records:

https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/query.py#L279

```
def __bool__(self):
    self._fetch_all()
    return bool(self._result_cache)
```

It might be a better idea to use `if queryset.count()` or `if queryset.exists()` if that's what you want.

Comment: @Selcuk I understand that and was expecting that it fetches everything. However I've been playing around with big querysets like iterating over them, slicing and all other things and it never froze the program. What might be the cause that in case of conditional expression it freezes.

Btw. I don't need workaround, I solved my problem, I'm just wondering what is happening in this case.

Comment: @Selcuk In the [link](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/query.py#L279) you have posted \_\_bool\_\_ calls _fetch_all() and so does \_\_iter\_\_ or \_\_len\_\_, difference is that bool function is called.

Comment: Alright, I tried some more functions line `len()` or iterating over the queryset, it also freezes until the program is killed, guess it is just too big. Though I remember iterating on same queryset other day without a problem.

Comment: Yeah, I was surprised when I saw your first comment as `__iter__` populates the `self._result_cache` in a similar way, so it shouldn't be any different. Glad to see that your last test confirms that.